# Linux server as a target for my C code

Tags: remote, c, debugging, eclipse

How to use a linux server as a target for my C code written on a different (Windows) machine. Including step by step debugging and etc... All that with Eclipse Env.

Comment: You have to be more specific. No one knows what you really want. I can just guess you want the Linux machine as a server for remote debugging. That can somehow be concluded from the context, but you should exactly ask about what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can *write* your code wherever you want, it's just text files.

If you wish to *compile* the code for a platform that is different from the one on which the compiler runs, then you need a cross compiler (by definition).

Cross compilers are commonly used to build code using powerful desktop computers than targets resource-limited embedded systems including smartphones.

Using Cygwin perhaps, you can most likely build `gcc` as a cross compiler to run on MS Windows and generate code for Linux amd64 (for example). Getting the whole toolchain up and running won't be trivial as you need include files and cross-compiled versions of basic libraries and more before you can start actually developing. You may want to look for someone who has already built and packaged all that.